# How to pass a list of values for an object property in $filter angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter a list of objects based on a property object (childrenIds) which is a list (can have more than one value). I tried this:

```
angular.forEach(myObjects, function(item){
                var childrenIds = item.childrenIds;
                if(childrenIds !== null){
                    var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.myObjects, {'id':childrenIds});

                }
});
```

here is an example of dataset:

```
[
 {id:1, name: parent1, hasChild:true, childrenIds:[2,3]}
 {id:2, name: child1, hasChild:false, childrenIds:[]}
 {id:3, name: child2, hasChild:false, childrenIds:[]}
 {id:4, name: parent2, hasChild:false, childrenIds:[]}
];
```

it is supposed to filter the children objects for a parent object. 
It is not working and I don't know how to tell angular that I am passing a list of values. I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: Could you share with us your filter code ? Moreover in your sample what you mean is more `{'id':childrenIds}` ?

Comment: Sorry for typo. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Could you also provide an example of your data set

Comment: I added to the question.

Comment: Remove the single quotes. `{id:childrenIds}`